# Binary Counter IC Counting Incorrectly

Tags: led, integrated-circuit, counter, binary

I'm currently trying to use [74HC163](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hc163.pdf) in a project, and it appears I have it wired up correctly, but it counts in a very strange sequence.  I wrote down the sequence as follows:

```
1 10 11 101 110 111 1001 1010 1011 1101 1110 1111
```

Translated into decimal:

```
1 2 3 5 6 7 9 10 11 13 14 15
```

As you can see, it skips several numbers including 0.  Why is this?

I have it wired as follows:

```
NOT CLR = 1
CLK = 10HZ clock from square wave generator
A = 0, B = 0, C = 0, D = 0
ENP = 1
GND = 0
VCC = 1
RCO = no connection
QA = LED, QB = LED, QC = LED, QD = LED
ENT = 1
NOT LOAD = 1
```

0 indicating unpowered, 1 indicating powered

Answer (score 1):

It was a defective wire, it had nothing to do with the chip.